# How to parse multi line XML in logstash?

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash

I have multiline XML files (~800 lines) in my s3 bucket and i want to index them in Elasticsearch but I can't parse them in logstash. Fields are sometimes empty so it's impossible to manually parse files.

My xml looks like:

```
<ServiceSalesClosed>
   <ErrorLevel>0</ErrorLevel>
   <ErrorMessage/>
   <LaborSaleCustomerPay>50.00</LaborSaleCustomerPay>`
   ...
```

In my input I have the config:

```
codec => multiline
{ 
pattern => "<ServiceSalesClosed.*"
what => next
}
```

In my filter the following config:

```
multiline { 
pattern => ["\t\t"]
what => next
}
```

Comment: You don't mention what it is that is causing you problems.  I general, use the multiline codec or filter to make a single event, then pass it to the xml{} filter.

Comment: I add my config in my post

Comment: What's that second filter supposed to do? There's no sign of tabs in your file. But check your `_source` field in elasticsearch - does this contain your complete XML or not? (And if it doesn't, can you post a sample of what it _does_ contain?)

Comment: I want lines matching a single event and I want every line to be a Json field

Comment: And what isn't working with what you've got?

Comment: '-source.message' doesn't contain my complet XML but only  "<ServiceSalesClosed>\n      <ErrorLevel>0</ErrorLevel>"

Comment: @Sobrique And in my console I have this mistake : "{:timestamp=>"2016-01-19T15:09:28.960000-0500", :message=>"Trouble parsing json", :source=>"message", :raw=>"</ServiceSalesClosed>", :exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')"

Comment: You wouldn't use both the codec and filter.  Your codec says: Anything that contains "<ServiceSalesClosed", keep with the next line, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Can you post your XML filter config?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like the problem is, you've got confused about your multiline codec and your XML filter.

Can I suggest you set your multiline up:

```
codec => multiline {
     pattern => "<ServiceSalesClosed>" 
     negate => "true"
     what => "previous"
}
```

This will take any line that *doesn't* contain this tag, and keep it with the previous line(s). This should group your XML stanzas into parsable chunks. You should see the results of this in `_source`.

Then in your *filter*:

```
filter {
  xml => {
    source => "message"
    target => "xml_content"
    xpath => [ "//ErrorLevel", "error_level" ] 
  }
}
```

This should then parse your XML, create fields in the elasticsearch DB for "xml_content" (including your parsed XML) but also specifically extract `ErrorLevel` into a field of it's own.

Comment: all my xml is in a tag " <ServiceSales xmlns="dmoes">; [...my events....] </ServicesSales> " I want to ignore this tag, I tried remove_tag but didn't work. Do you know how I can do it? @Sobrique

Comment: That would be a separate question,  I suggest you ask it as such.

Comment: I need to add `auto_flush_interval => 1` to process last event.