# need Logstash configuration to parse xml file

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, xml-parsing, logstash, elastic-stack

I need to parse the xml file from Netsparker vulnerability scanner output.
there are many ways and I'm confused how to do it.
ELK v6.5.2

**HERE is the xml file :**
https://www.netsparker.com/statics/faq/Threat%20Classification%20-%20Requirement%20Mappings.xml

I've also tried this code :

```
input {

file { 
  path => "/home/test/xml.xml"
  start_position => "beginning"
  type => "xml"
  codec => multiline {
    pattern => "<ThreatsTable>" 
    negate => "true"
    what => "previous"
    max_lines => "10000"
  }
}
}

filter {

xml {
  source => "message"
  target => "parsed"
}
}

output {

elasticsearch {
  codec => json
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
}
}
```

I need every field in the xml file,
as you can see there is one "ThreatTable" and many other "ThreatsRow", each with 12 lines of code. ( sorry for bad language )
so what is need is to have each ThreatsRow as a log and every log with its fields like : SEVERITY , SHORTNAME and ...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34896295/6113627. The issue is with `pattern => "<ThreatsTable>" `, you'll have to use `pattern => "<ThreatsRow>" ` to have single log with each threatsRow

Comment: thanks man -@baudsp